# c# enable button if textbox has data

Tags: c#, winforms

EDIT:
Sorry for the lack of information, its a winform app in C#
And the post is not duplicate. 
The problem happens when i close the form witch contains the report to edit the previous form values and then the button to print the report again stays disabled instead of remaining enabled.

I found several similar posts but none resolved my issue. 
I have the following code do enable a `button` if a `textbox` is empty:

```
button3.Enabled = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resposta.Text);
```

The code works but the problem is, if i click next and for some reason want to go back to alter something the `button` stays disabled even with data in the `textbox`.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Next" and "go back"? How are you doing this?

Comment: Add that code to the `TextChanged` event of the textbox you are checking

Comment: I don't even know how you're having this next and go back functionalities, but since the state of the textbox is being changed, I believe a form_Load function is running. Just add this same code to your form_Load

Comment: @PhiterFernandes `page_load`? The tag is winforms

Comment: The app runs a formula and gives a result in a textbox then the button "print" is enabled and clicking it prints a report with various data. If i close the form witch contains the report to alter some data the button print stays disabled

Comment: I know, it's not page_load. It's form_load. I got confused

Comment: I´,m not sure the duplicate matches. As far as I understand OP he doesn´t change the textbox´ value, instead he´s opening and closing a second form. No idea how this could affect the textbox at all.

Comment: Are you using the TextChanged event of your textbox? If not, then you should.

Comment: Did you tried to add that code to the `TextChanged` event as we have told you?

Comment: Yes, but if i do, the button stays disabled

Comment: Because `resposta.Text` is empty i guess,so that's the expected behavior. Why don't you edit your question and tell us exactly the behavior you expect(i.e. when the button must be enabled and when not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a but unclear what the problem is, but it seems you are trying to use WinForms as some MVC with binding (like angular), but when you do assignment it does this one time only in WinForms, no binding is created.

So you need to figure out when you need to call this again. (TextChange, some button click, etc.)